# Mirror and Offset UV Islands procedurally with Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, mirror

I am trying to mirror and then offset each island of my uv's. The UV creation and placement is by hand, but I would like to procedurally place their mirrored versions like so:
[image]

My problem is that I'm not sure how to get just the mirrored uv information, and then offset them consistently on a per island basis.

Here's my setup:
[image]
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: How do you know the mirrored half is not going to be outside 0>1? Do you want to center all the islands, too?

Comment: I hadn't thought of centering them, but that might work. 
In my use case, all coordinates would be entirely outside of the 0>1 uv space. My hope was to mirror one side of a uv shell, and then automatically apply the mirrored half.
Maybe offsetting the UV after I mirror them would work, and having the direction they offset be based off a vertex group assignment?

Comment: I've had a preliminary look at this, and it's really hard to answer generally, IMO. There are so many undefined possible edge-cases. eg. What if a UV island doesn't have a geometry-boundary on the mirror-plane? or: What if a seam is on the mirror-plane, but not straight?  etc.  I wonder if you can constrain the problem in a way that suits your purposes?

Answer (score -1):

Constraining the problem really helped. I figured out the process of doing this in Geometry Nodes, which involved first manually centering the UV's, and then mirroring them with geometry Nodes. Then I could use a manual material assignment and have Geometry Nodes offset to the left or right based on that assignment.
That worked really well, but then when it came to exporting to a game engine or another modeling program, I found that once the Geometry Node modifier is applied, it stores the UVMap information as an Attribute instead of as a UVMap. I could manually Convert Attribute in the Object Data properties, but that would take way to much time, so I took that approach and figured out a way of getting the same result with modifiers and vertex groups.

If anyone is interested in that solution it can be found here:
https://youtu.be/0NThmkqwa0M

And if anyone wants my Geometry Nodes setup, which I got similar end results (sans being unable to use it in other programs easily) then I can post that here too.

Thanks Robin, those questions really helped guide me to a solution down both paths!

Comment: Hi, I didn't downvote, but I suspect you got downvoted because you relied heavily on outside sources (your youtube video-- at least, I assume it's yours), you talked about problems with details unmentioned in the problem (GN nodes -> export to game engine), and because you didn't provide the full solution ("I can post that.")  It's probably too late, but to avoid downvotes, edit the problem to include relevant details like that, and detail your solution on SE rather than elsewhere.  Although I understand it may not be worth the trouble; after all, a downvote is really nothing.